# Angular chosen dont't focus on tab

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

In navigation with TAB, the chosen fields are ignored, always jumping to the next field.
This error occurs in all pages of my web application.

My application uses:

- Angular v1.5.0
- Bootstrap Ace
- Chosen JQuery v1.4.2

Any idea what is causing this problem?

Comment: try use the directive [angular-chosen](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen/releases/tag/1.4.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was a conflit with a lib ace.min.css that has a class who give this error. Just remore it and it will work like hell!

The class is:
.chosen-container .chosen-drop {
    display: none
}

Remove it and u are ready to go!